# how to set background color to the text only in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flexbox

in html I can achieve this by

```
<span style="background-color:red">ketan</span>
```

but in react native how to implement this so that color will be applied to the text only.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html Look for styling tips in docs.

Answer (score 23):

If you want the background color to only encompass the text, you can use this:

```
<Text style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', alignSelf: 'flex-start'}}>
    Ketan
</Text>
```

And just change alignSelf as needed, you need to set this property if you dont want the text to take the whole width of the container

Comment: Worked like a charm. Not having AlignSelf was the issue

Comment: Worked for me, also you can add a parent view that you can set properties like: alignSelf: 'flex-start',
          borderRadius: 10,
          overflow: 'hidden',
          backgroundColor: 'red',

Answer (score 3):

In react native you can directly use "Text" component and apply "backgroundColor" style to it as follows:

```
<Text> 
    <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "red", color: "white" }}>color
    </Text>
</Text>
```

Comment: <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>ketan
</Text>

Comment: @ketan kulkarni, not getting what you mean to say here.

Comment: @ Sandip Lipane I have tried many combinations like applied background colour to text, view but still, it is taking the full width  I am trying to design a button using TouchableOpacity and Text and i want background color applied to the text only

Comment: @ketan kulkarni, Please visit this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html and try modifying existing examples with backgroundColor style. I have verified and it is working. Can you please verify it once?

Comment: it is working if i write     <Text>
        background
        <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "red", color: "white" }}>color</Text>
      </Text>

Comment: Yes, you have to add nested text.

Comment: this works for me <Text>
        <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "red", color: "white" }}>color</Text>
      </Text>

Answer (score 1):

In react native you have `Text` component to display text.

To set color of `Text`, you can use `color` property of it

```
<Text style={{color:'#ff0000'}}>Your Text</Text>
```

And for background color of that text, you can use `View` and than set `backgroundColor` of that `View`

Comment: i have tried following

1)
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "red"
        }}
      >
        <Text>n</Text>
      </View>

2)
      <View>
        <Text
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "red"
          }}
        >
          n
        </Text>
      </View>

but output is same

Answer (score 0):

you can't on IOS. set backgroundColor for extra `View`

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: 'red',flex:1}}><Text >ketan
    </Text></View>
```

Comment: try with `flex:1` or `flex:0`

Comment: this works for me   `<Text> <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "red", color: "white" }}>color</Text> </Text> `

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
<Text style={{backgroundColor:'red', color:'white'}}>{'Message'}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Text } from 'react-native';

<Text style={{backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
  Ketan
</Text>
```

In order to put text in ReactNative, you need `Text` component. And you can apply `backgroundColor` onto `style` property.

Here's a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/BkNqffjmX) as a demo to show usage and as playground for you to play around